# SQL Query works with `like` but not with equals for some ids

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a mariadb db with an `event` table and a few entries:

```
MariaDB [db]> select id from event;
+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| 307304a6-a6f9-11ea-a857-0242c0a84006 |
| 324b3d58-a704-11ea-a857-0242c0a84006 |
| 34a7420a-d893-11ea-aa55-0242c0a84005 |
| 48ff5659-f738-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005 |
| 60daad8b-f64f-11ea-bb99-0242c0a84005 |
| 64f31bde-afa0-11ea-9088-0242c0a84006 |
| 6ecb1814-b786-11ea-bc7d-0242c0a84005 |
| 7a9431e3-d88e-11ea-aa55-0242c0a84005 |
| 7b3a2a08-f64f-11ea-bb99-0242c0a84005 |
| 859c9507-d61a-11ea-aa55-0242c0a84005 |
| 956104e5-f73a-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005 |
| b3b78b4e-a6b2-11ea-a857-0242c0a84006 |
| de844d58-fbcf-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005 |
| f03fe24b-fbcf-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005 |
| f9c563ee-fcec-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005 |
+--------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.015 sec)
```

I have a simple query like the following which selects an event by its id. For some ids copied from the select result above, it returns the correct event as expected, however for some ids it returns nothing:

```
MariaDB [db]> select id from event where id = '307304a6-a6f9-11ea-a857-0242c0a84006';
+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| 307304a6-a6f9-11ea-a857-0242c0a84006 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.016 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select id from event where id = '48ff5659-f738-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005';
Empty set (0.015 sec)
```

However, if I use `like` instead of `=` and add a placeholder at the beginning, I get the result I want:

```
MariaDB [db]> select id from event where id like '%48ff5659-f738-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005';
+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| 48ff5659-f738-11ea-9ba6-0242c0a84005 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.014 sec)
```

I already thought about non-printable ascii characters but ruled that out:

```
MariaDB [db]> SELECT * FROM event WHERE id NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
Empty set (0.016 sec)

MariaDB [db]> SELECT * FROM event WHERE id regexp '[^ -~]';
Empty set (0.015 sec)

MariaDB [db]> SELECT * FROM event WHERE id like '%\0%';
Empty set (0.017 sec)
```

The database is `latin1` encoded, the table in question is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

**How is it possible the same query works for some ids and not others? How can I debug this?**

Comment: seems most likely you have extra spaces.  try `where id not regexp '^[-a-z0-9]+$' or length(id) <> 36`

Comment: Yes, its seems to be some extra spaces. I create a database and a table with the same format and data and I dont have any problem with the same queries.

Comment: What column type have the `id` column?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  You should not need `LIKE` or `REGEXP` if `id` is properly declared.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=9a06cb7f8bbefa47a69dfadc19ad17c2&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb 
Can you export SQL from your table and reproduce it as SQL fiddle?